# Apache Server: Redirection via http headers

Tags: apache, redirect

I am trying to force browser to use https even when the user enters http URL. The idea is to use http response headers from the server. I am able to implement redirection using redirect (in site.conf) & Rewrite (which is disliked universally) but want to test out this method too.

Now I have tried adding the the following to my /etc/apache/sites-enabled/mysite.conf but despite the browser receiving the header response the user is not redirected to https (default apache page is shown):

Header set Location https://www.example.com/
Header set X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=180; includeSubdomains"

Do I have to change anything else in the apache configuration to achieve this? (all modules are correctly loaded)

Answer (score 0):

The Location header is only used for redirect responses (with a HTTP response code of 3XX) or Created responses (with a HTTP response code of 201):
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2

Just setting the header on a random page will not make the browser redirect.

When you use apache Redirect and Rewrite rules they set the response header AND add the location header. I really don't know why you'd want to do this manually.

And rewrite is not "universally disliked". It just overused when redirect would be simpler and more efficient in a lot of cases. If you need something more complicated then Rewrite is the right tool to use.

Finally you should not sent the Strict-Transport-Security header on a HTTP response (and the browser will rightly ignore it you do) but only on a HTTPS responses.

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to "learn" apache administration so didn't want to miss out on any techniques. Thanks for clearing it up for me.